# In my multi thread program, pthread_cond_signal seems to be lost?

Tags: c, multithreading

In my program, i have two threads:
thread1 execute function thread1:

```
 void thread1() {
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
        memset(recvbuf, 0, sizeof(recvbuf));
        printf("prepare recv\n");
        int len = recvfrom(server_sockfd, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_sockaddr, &sin_len);
        printf("send signal to screen\n");
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond4);
        printf("has sent signal, start to wait\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond3,&mutex2);
        printf("wait end\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
    }
}
```

thread2 execute function thread2:

```
void screen_output(void *ptr) {
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
        printf("screen pthread wait condition\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond4,&mutex2);
        printf("recv signal\n");
        printf("the data from client:%s\n", recvbuf);
        free(recvbuf);
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond3);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
    }
}
```

The output result like this:

```
prepare recv
send signal to screen
has sent signal, start to wait
screen pthread wait condition
```

from output, In thread1, **pthread_cond_signal(&cond4);** has executed.

But in thread2, thread block in **pthread_cond_wait(&cond4,&mutex2);**
Why happens that?

Comment: Because the thread wasn't waiting when the signal arrived? Condition variables don't remember signals.

Comment: Don't use condition variables as "state" or resource counting. Use them as *signals* to communicate a *change* in state to some outer predicate data protected by your mutex. The latter state should be verified when coming out of a `pthread_cond_wait` successfully so as to avoid potential spurious wake-ups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you call `pthread_cond_wait`, you have to check that the thing you are waiting for hasn't already happened. And before you call `pthread_cond_signal` (or before you release the mutex if you call it while holding the mutex) you have to change the shared state protected by that mutex so that other thread will know that the thing they are waiting for has happened.

You are using a condition variable as if it was a semaphore. It's not. Condition variables are stateless and it's up to your code to track the state with the associated mutex. Your code doesn't do that.

You code has some shared state -- which thread is supposed to be running and which thread is supposed to be waiting. To use a condition variable to wait for that state to change, that state must be protected with the associated mutex. But you don't even track that state *at* *all*! So how can your code know when it's supposed to wait?

Here's a start on a possible fix:

```
 void thread1() {
    while (1)
    {
        char *buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
        memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);
        printf("prepare recv\n");
        int len = recvfrom(server_sockfd, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0,
            (struct sockaddr *)&server_sockaddr, &sin_len);
        printf("send signal to screen\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
        recv_buf = buf; // tell other threads there's data to receive
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond4);
        printf("has sent signal, start to wait\n");
        while (recv_buf != NULL) // wait until data is consumed
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond3,&mutex2);
        printf("wait end\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
    }
}

void screen_output(void *ptr) {
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
        printf("screen pthread wait condition\n");
        while (recv_buf == NULL) // wait until there's data to consume
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond4,&mutex2);

        printf("recv signal\n");
        printf("the data from client:%s\n", recvbuf);
        free(recv_buf);
        recv_buf = NULL; // tell other threads we consumed the data
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond3);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
    }
}
```

Notice how `recv_buf` now holds the shared state and how the threads wait *for* the shared state to have the necessary value? That's how you have to use a condition variable.

Comment: Re "*Condition variables are stateless*", To be clear, this means that signaling a cond var only wakes up a thread currently waiting on it. If no thread is currently waiting on it, nothing happens. Thus, the `lock();  while (!condition()) wait(); ...; unlock();` / `lock();  ...; signal(); unlock();` pattern.

Comment: @ikegami It means more than that. It also means they don't know when they should sleep and when they shouldn't so can't reliably ensure they stop sleeping at the right time. (This includes spurious wakeups and also things that appear to be spurious wakeups but aren't such as when thread A wakes up but finds thread B already did whatever thread A was supposed to do.)